# Passing variables verbatim from autoconf.ac to automake.am

Tags: variables, autoconf, automake

How can I pass a string verbatim from autoconf.ac to automake.am.

Example, in `autoconf.ac`, I'd like to give `MYPATH = "-I$MYENVPATH -I$SOMEOTHERPATH"` and subsequently, get `MYPATH` exactly as I gave, inside `automake.am`

`AC_SUBST` is trying to deference and cause issues.

Comment: Could you show exactly what you wrote in `configure.ac` and describe precisely what the *issues* caused by `AC_SUBST` are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the shell from evaluating variables inside strings (if that is whay you meant by "`AC_SUBST` is trying to dereference"), use simple quotes:

```
AC_SUBST([MYPATH], ['-I$MYENVPATH -I$SOMEOTHERPATH'])
```

This should output the following line in `Makefile`:

```
MYPATH = -I$MYENVPATH -I$SOMEOTHERPATH
```

However this does not make a lot of sense to me: `make` needs variable names to be enclosed in braces or parentheses (when their name has more than one letter).  Probably what you really want is something like:

```
AC_SUBST([MYPATH], ['-I${MYENVPATH} -I${SOMEOTHERPATH}'])
```

Comment: He may need the `$` escaped, as well: `AC_SUBST([MYPATH], ['-I$$MYENVPATH -I$$SOMEOTHERPATH'])`